# How to differentiate between 'Enter' and 'Return' keys in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, keycode

Some desktop apps treat the 'carriage return' key and the numpad's 'enter' key differently. I've noticed that these two keys generate the same keyCode (13) in Javascript (jQuery).

Are they converted to be equal in the browser environment, or is it possible to differentiate between them (ie. make the CR make a new line in a text area, and the 'enter' key submit it's form ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

See Jan Wolters’ treatise on [Javascript Madness: Keyboard Events](http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html).

`Enter` and `Numpad Enter` both give the same keycode, i.e. 13, because browsers do not differentiate between the two keys.  To be honest, nor do most environments.  It is possible to differentiate between them using the Windows API (for example), but it does take extra effort to do so.  This, however, falls outside the scope of the browser’s abstraction.

**UPDATE**

As Bill Thorne rightfully [mentions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27926470/3092116), the `KeyboardEvent` object sports a `location` property nowadays.

From the [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/location):

> Possible values are:
>
> `DOM_KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD`   `0` The key has
>   only one version, or can't be distinguished between the left and right
>   versions of the key, and was not pressed on the numeric keypad or a
>   key that is considered to be part of the keypad.
>
> `DOM_KEY_LOCATION_LEFT`   `1` The key was the left-hand version of the key;
>   for example, the left-hand Control key was pressed on a standard 101
>   key US keyboard. This value is only used for keys that have more that
>   one possible location on the keyboard.
>
> `DOM_KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT`  `2` The
>   key was the right-hand version of the key; for example, the right-hand
>   Control key is pressed on a standard 101 key US keyboard. This value
>   is only used for keys that have more that one possible location on the
>   keyboard.
>
> `DOM_KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD` `3`  The key was on the numeric
>   keypad, or has a virtual key code that corresponds to the numeric
>   keypad.
>
> *Note: When NumLock is locked, Gecko always returns
>   DOM_KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD for the keys on the numeric pad. Otherwise,
>   when NumLock is unlocked and the keyboard actually has a numeric
>   keypad, Gecko always returns DOM_KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD too. On the other
>   hand, if the keyboard doesn't have a keypad, such as on a notebook
>   computer, some keys become Numpad only when NumLock is locked. When
>   such keys fires key events, the location attribute value depends on
>   the key. That is, it must not be DOM_KEY_LOCATION_NUMPAD. Note:
>   NumLock key's key events indicate DOM_KEY_LOCATION_STANDARD both on
>   Gecko and Internet Explorer.*

Comment: `location` gives me `undefined` on mac. Is there another way to do it?

Answer (score 14):

I am providing an update as this question still appears near the top of google search results.

Per MDN, [`KeyboardEvent.keyCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode) and [`KeyBoardEvent.charCode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/charCode) are deprecated and should no longer be used.

`KeyboardEvent` keys can be determined by accessing the [`KeyboardEvent.key`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key),  [`KeyboardEvent.code`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code), and [`KeyboardEvent.location`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/location) properties as necessary.

`KeyboardEvent.key` returns generally what you see in a text editor for output keys and the name on non-output keys (including being case-sensitive).

`KeyboardEvent.code` returns a string description of the key.

`KeyboardEvent.location` returns an integer between 0 and 3 to signify the area of the keyboard the key is located in (standard, left, right, and numpad respectively).

[Understanding the difference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/KeyboardEvent) between these properties can help to determine which will be most appropriate for your given situation. In the case of this question: `event.key` will return the same output (`"Enter"`) for both the 'carriage return' and 'numpad enter'keys, while `event.code` will return `"Enter"` and `"NumpadEnter"` respectively.

In this case, if you wanted to differentiate between numpad and keyboard keys, you could use `event.code`. If you wanted their operation to be the same, `event.key` would be a better choice.

If you wanted to differentiate between other keys, such as the left and right `Ctrl` keys, you would also want to look at the `event.location` property.

I'm adding a small keyboard event playground to see the difference between these event properties. Credit to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code) for providing [the concept](https://jsfiddle.net/api/mdn/) that I only slightly modified below:

```js
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(event) {

  let str = "key = '" + event.key + 
              "' &nbsp code = '" + event.code + "'" + 
              "' &nbsp location = '" + event.location + "'" ;
              
  let el = document.createElement("span");
  
  el.innerHTML = str + "<br/>";
 
  document.getElementById("output").appendChild(el);
  
}, true);
```

```css
#output {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  overflow-y: auto;
  margin-left: 4em
}

#output span {
  line-height: 2em;
}

#output :nth-child(2n) {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/code -->

<p>
  Press keys on the keyboard to see what the KeyboardEvent's key and code values are for  each one.
</p>
<div id="output"></div>
```

Comment: thank you for 'NumpadEnter' code, I was looking for something like that

Answer (score 13):

If there is a key on the keyboard that is physically different, browser applications should be just as capable as desktop applications to differentiate.

With the latest versions of Chrome (39.0.2171.95 m), Firefox (32.0.3), IE (11.0.9600.17501) and Opera (12.17), the keyboard event object now has the location property.  I would presume this property has been around for a while, although it is lightly documented.

Tests of onkeydown reveal that when the "normal" enter key is pressed, keyCode=13 and location=0; when the numpad enter is pressed, keyCode=13 and location=3.

So the following code can be used to set key==13 if the enter, key==176 if numpad enter:

```
window.onkeydown=function(ev)
{
    var e= ev || window.event,
      key = e.keyCode || e.which;

    if ((key==13) &&
        (e.location===3))
      key=176; // 176 is the scancode for the numpad enter
    // continued....
}
```

Comment: `e.location` just gives me `undefined` on mac (safari and ff). Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

You can differentiate both by `code` property of the event. For the numpad one, it returns `NumpadEnter` and for the other one it returns `Enter`. Alternatively, you can also use `location` property which works in all cases, unlike `code` property. For numpad Enter, it returns 3 whereas, for other Enter it returns 0.