# Differentiate between ENTER and RETURN in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-11-alexandria

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418313/how-to-differentiate-between-enter-and-return-keys-in-javascript) tells how to do so in JavaScript, but how does one do it in a Delphi program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Windows actually gives you this information in the `WM_KEYDOWN` message.

To try this, create a new VCL application and add a `WM_KEYDOWN` message procedure to the main form:

```pascal
procedure WMKeyDown(var Message: TWMKeyDown); message WM_KEYDOWN;
```

implemented as

```pascal
procedure TForm1.WMKeyDown(var Message: TWMKeyDown);
begin
  case Message.CharCode of
    VK_RETURN:
      begin
        if Message.KeyData shr 16 and KF_EXTENDED <> 0 then
          ShowMessage('Enter (numeric keypad) down')
        else
          ShowMessage('Return down')
      end;
  end;
end;
```

Indeed, the documentation for [`WM_KEYDOWN`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/wm-keydown) links to [Keyboard Input Overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#keystroke-message-flags) and then the [Extended-Key Flag](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/inputdev/about-keyboard-input#extended-key-flag) section:

> The extended-key flag indicates whether the keystroke message originated from one of the additional keys on the Enhanced 101/102-key keyboard. The extended keys consist of [...] and ENTER keys in the numeric keypad.

Comment: Thanks. This led me to the solution (I wanted it globally and not only on a single form). I implemented it via TApplicationEvents.OnMessage instead in order to do so.

Comment: @HeartWare Alternatively, you could set the Form's `KeyPreview` property to true and then use the MainForm's `OnKey...` event(s) to handle the keystrokes globally.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That won't allow me to tell the difference between the RETURN key (the one on the letters area) and the ENTER key (the one on the numerical keyboard), as both return VK_RETURN in the Key parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone wants a similar solution to the one I implemented, here's a UNIT that you can simply include to make the Enter key on the numerical keypad return a different VK_ code:

```
UNIT HeartWare.Keyboard;

INTERFACE

USES WinAPI.Windows, WinAPI.Messages;

CONST
  VK_ENTER = $000F; // Unused VK_ keyboard code

IMPLEMENTATION

USES VCL.AppEvnts;

TYPE
  TAppEvents    = CLASS(TApplicationEvents)
                    PROCEDURE   Message(VAR Msg : tagMSG ; VAR Handled : BOOLEAN);
                  END;

{ TAppEvents }

PROCEDURE TAppEvents.Message(VAR Msg : tagMSG ; VAR Handled : BOOLEAN);
  BEGIN
    CASE Msg.message OF
      WM_KEYDOWN : IF (MSG.WParam=VK_RETURN) AND (MSG.LParam SHR 16 AND KF_EXTENDED<>0) THEN MSG.WParam:=VK_ENTER
    END
  END;


INITIALIZATION

  WITH TAppEvents.Create(NIL) DO OnMessage:=Message

END.
```

Simply save the above code to HeartWare.Keyboard.PAS and include this UNIT in one of your own (f.ex. the UNIT for the Main Form), and it will install a message hook that will translate the Enter key on the numerical keyboard to report VK_ENTER instead of VK_RETURN.