# Is there a way to distinguish different Enter-presses?

Tags: javascript, input, browser, keyboard

On the standard keyboard there are two <kbd>Enter</kbd>-keys, can I distinguish which was pressed? More importantly: when reading barcodes into the input field on some occasions I'd like to cut out the Enter sent after the barcode value. I don't want to reprogram barcode readers not to send the Enter, because most times it is exactly what I need. So how to distinguish different Enters?

I made simple [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ypm6tbhn/23/) to play with, but all the different ways to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> seem indistinguishable.

```
const myForm = document.getElementById("form");
const myInput = document.getElementById("test");
const myOutput = document.getElementById("output");

myForm.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  myOutput.innerHTML += "<br>form submit prevented";
});

myInput.addEventListener("change", (e) => {
  const val = e.target.value;
  const chars = val.split("");
  chars.forEach((c) => myOutput.innerHTML += `<br>char: ${c}`)
});

myInput.addEventListener("keydown", (e) => {
  console.log(e.key);
  myOutput.innerHTML += "<br>key: " + e.key;
});
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to differentiate between 'Enter' and 'Return' keys in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418313/how-to-differentiate-between-enter-and-return-keys-in-javascript)

Comment: @tomdartmoor to a certain extent, it gives me no ground to work with barcode's Enter, still

Comment: It might be worth trying to distinguish which enter key the barcode enter is mapped to, although browsers seem to treat both as the same key. Would it be possible to block the submit event from running? or have another check inside the submit event which only runs if some conditions are met etc?

Comment: @tomdartmoor Actually, I am not worried about the submit, but bit finer logistics between the inputs. But, yes, if I can't make a difference between Enters, I must use some patterns to avoid undesired actions.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot differentiate between the two keys in a browser.

See this previous Question:

[How to differentiate between 'Enter' and 'Return' keys in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5418313/how-to-differentiate-between-enter-and-return-keys-in-javascript)

Comment: Thank you for the link, this referred answer actually makes it possible to distinguish between 2 Enter-keys, but unfortunately not the barcode reader (gives the same code as "big" Enter)